# Change the font style

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When I change the font of `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` property to bold, it change perfectly but when I build my solution my settings is automatically changes to regular font, I don't know what's happening why my font changes when I build the solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Clean Solution` and `Re-Build Solution` your Project .

Comment: did you try to add some control(TextBox, etc.) from your `forms` and when you run your project then the control you added is still their?

Comment: @gauravsomani: try closing VS, and delete OBJ and BIN folders, then reopen your project.